# Using Beaker on Google App Engine (Django)

Tags: django, google-app-engine, session, beaker

How do we use Beaker to implement sessions on Google App Engine? (I say Beaker because gmemsess is short-lived, and therefore not suitable). There seem to be no examples online.

We're using Django 1.1 via App Engine Helper (not app-engine-patch).

Comment: Can you please help me with configuring beaker with django 1.2 on appengine ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the session type as 'ext:google', like [this](http://github.com/Arachnid/aeoid/blob/master/aeoid/middleware.py#L50). You also need to edit beaker/cache.py, deleting the section that uses pkg_resources to search for plugins, as this isn't supported on App Engine.